# Law of iterated logarithm proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to master this proof of iterated logarithm. However, I get stuck at the last part.
Here is a  [link](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/F12/Junior_Seminar/LIL.pdf)

In the last two line at fourth page. We calculate the probability that: 
$$  
f(n)=\sqrt{2nln(lnn)} $$ 
$$
(*) P(R_k\ge(1-\epsilon/2)f(a^k))=P(X_{a^{k-1}(a-1)}\ge(1-\epsilon/2)f(a^k)) $$ 
Then using this: 
$$(1-\epsilon/2)f(a^k-a^{k-1})\le(1-\epsilon/4)f(a^k)$$ 
and probably this: 
$$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac {f(a^k)}{f(a^k-a^{k-1})}=\sqrt{\frac{a}{a-1}}$$
 we calculate the lower bond: 
$$P(X_{a^{k-1}(a-1)}\ge(1-\epsilon/2)f(a^{k-1}(a-1)))\ge \frac{c}{k \log{a}}$$ 
Using this, conclude that 
$$P(R_k\ge(1-\epsilon/2)f(a^k))$$ 
for infinitely many k . 
However I don't get  why it works because 
$$ (1-\epsilon/2)f(a^k-a^{k-1}) \le (1-\epsilon/2)f(a^k)$$ 
So we can not just use this lower bond for $(*)$ . Does it use the behavior of $f(a^k)$ and $f(a^k-a^{k-1})$ in infinity?

Shouldn't it look like: 
$$(1-\epsilon/4)f(a^k-a^{k-1})\ge(1-\epsilon/2)f(a^k)$$
It should occur for some a and then we can correctly deduce the inequality for probabilities. Any suggestions if I am right will be invaluable.

However, we also assume that
$$(1 + \epsilon/4)f(a^{k-1})\le((\epsilon/2)f(a^k))$$ 
I have no idea, why it works for $\epsilon \le1$. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Recall the definition of $f$.

Comment: $f=\sqrt{2nln(lnn)}$

Comment: Please include this in the post.